# Unique values between 2 values of foreign keys in mysql

Tags: mysql

- I have the requirement to find unique vulnerabilities between two
  releases.
- Table1 has workspace id's mapped to release names, where
  Workspace is Primary key.
- Table2 has workspace id's mapped to vulnerabilities. In Table 2 Workspace is not the primary key and just normal field.
- I need to find out the unique vulnerabilities between any two workspace id's.
- In below example if i compare 101 and 102 workspace i should get "VulnUnique1" and "VulnUnique2".

So my final result should be like this:

```
-----------------------------------------
|    Release 1 and Release 2 Comparison |
----------------------------------------- 
| VulnUnique1                           | 
| VulnUnique2                           | 
----------------------------------------
```

Table1: workspace table

```
------------------------------
| Workspace |        Name    |
|-----------|----------------|
|   101     | Release1       |
|   102     | Release2       |
|   103     | Release3       |
|   104     | Release4       |
------------------------------
```

Table 2: vulnerability table

```
------------------------------
| Workspace |        Name    |
|-----------|----------------|
|   101     | Vuln1          |
|   101     | Vuln2          |
|   101     | Vuln3          |
|   102     | Vuln1          |
|   102     | Vuln2          |
|   102     | Vuln3          |
|   102     | VulnUnique1    |
|   102     | VulnUnique2    |
------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM
vulnerability v
GROUP BY v.Name
HAVING Count(*)=1
```

**Demo**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/84324b/7

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.